# Advanced custom fields: Group Field Array

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have created a field group that contains a true/false field and a few other fields.

My code looks like this : -

```
$condition = get_sub_field('field_name');
if($condition == 1){
    //$condition is true
    $array[] = "string";
}
```

However when I add this to my array and print the array (using a foreach loop) it displays an error "array to string conversion error".

```
 foreach ($array as $array_item) {
        echo  $array_item;
 }
```

Will having other fields in the group cause even the if to be a part of an array? What is the best way to manage field groups.

Comment: `$array[] = "string"` is assigning an string to an array so it tries to convert the array to string, which is not possible so it causes a conversion error. If you are trying to add `"string"` into `$array[]` you need to use `array_push()` method. Alternatively you can define the key of the array and set it like this: `$array["my_key"] = "string"`

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz You're completely wrong, `$array[] = "string"` is a valid syntax and it works the same as `array_push()`, but it is faster. @neverin772 Please share code of your foreach loop where you're displaying `$array` - you probably have error there.

Comment: @rob006 I added my foreach loop.

Comment: I suggest to replace `echo  $array_item` with `var_dump($array_item)` and check what is in it.

Comment: think, the problem is with this line: `if($condition == 1){`: `get_sub_field` may return array, and from here is coming your error

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve this myself, issue was caused by trying to convert an array to string further up in the code.